# Decomposition of Lie subspaces

Tags: connections, reductive-groups

If $M=G/H$ is a reductive homogeneous space then we can write $\frak{g}=\frak{m}+\frak{h}$
where $[\frak{h}, \frak{m}]\subset \frak{m}$. Here $\frak{g}$ and $\frak{h}$ are the Lie algebras of $G$ and $H$ respectively. Let $T_o$ be the torsion of the canonical connection (of the second kind) w.r.t. this decomposition at $o=\pi(e)$.

My questions is: when can we decompose $\frak{m}$ as 
$$\frak{m}=\frak{m}_0+\frak{m}_1$$
where  $T_o(X_1,X_2)=0$ for $X_1,X_2\in \frak{m}_0$, $T_o(Y_1,Y_2)\ne 0$ for $Y_1,Y_2\in \frak{m}_1$, and $T_o(X,Y)=0$ for $X\in \frak{m}_0$ and $Y\in \frak{m}_1$? For example, any compact connected Lie group $G$ is a semidirect product of its commutator subgroup $G^\prime$ and an Abelian subgroup $G_0$. We can therefore take $\frak{m}_0$ to be the Lie algebra of $G_0$ and $\frak{m}_1=[\frak{g},\frak{g}]$, the Lie algebra of $G^\prime$. It's well known that the torsion for $G$ is given by $T_e(X,Y)=-[X,Y]$.

Comment: I guess you are asking about a decomposition of $\mathfrak{m}$ as $\mathrm{Ad}(H)$-modules.  Otherwise, it seems to me that you can always decompose it.  The torsion of the canonical connection defines a linear map $\tau : \mathfrak{m} \to \mathrm{End}(\mathfrak{m})$ by $\tau(X) = [X,-]_{\mathfrak{m}}$ and it follows that $\mathfrak{m}_0 = \ker \tau$.

Comment: Also, the condition $T_0(Y_1,Y_2) \neq 0$ for $Y_1, Y_2 \in \mathfrak{m}_1$ cannot be true because $T_0$ is skewsymmetric, so $T_0(Y,Y) = 0$ for all $Y$.  I suppose you mean that for all $Y_1 \in \mathfrak{m}_1$, there exists $Y_2 \in \mathfrak{m}_1$ so that $T_0(Y_1,Y_2) \neq 0$?

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill What I meant was $T_o(\frak{m}_1,\frak{m}_1)\ne 0$. Also, in the decomposition, $\frak{m}_0$ is a subspace and $\frak{m}_1$ is a semi-simple subalgebra of $(\frak{m}$,$T_o)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am starting to think that you can always do this, but perhaps I am missing something at this later hour.

The torsion of the canonical connection at the origin defines a skewsymmetric bilinear map $T_0: \Lambda^2 \mathfrak{m} \to \mathfrak{m}$ by
$$
T_0(X,Y) = -[X,Y]_{\mathfrak{m}}
$$
where the subscript indicates the natural projection $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{h} \oplus \mathfrak{m} \to \mathfrak{m}$.  In turn this defines a linear map $\tau : \mathfrak{m} \to \operatorname{End}(\mathfrak{m})$ by
$$
\tau(X) = - [X, -]_{\mathfrak{m}}
$$

We define $\mathfrak{m}_0 = \ker \tau$.  I claim that $\mathfrak{m}_0$ is an $\operatorname{Ad}(H)$-module.  I assume $H$ is connected, so it is enough to show that if $\tau(X) = 0$, then for all $Z \in \mathfrak{h}$, $\tau([Z,X])=0$.  This follows from the following calculation (using the Jacobi identity of $\mathfrak{g}$):
$$
\tau([Z,X]) = [[Z,X],-]_{\mathfrak{m}} = [Z,[X,-]]_{\mathfrak{m}} - [X,[Z,-]]_{\mathfrak{m}}
$$
The first term in the RHS vanishes because it can be rewritten as
$$[Z,[X,-]_{\mathfrak{m}}]_{\mathfrak{m}}$$
and we use that $\tau(X) = 0$.  The second term in the RHS vanishes because of reductivity and the fact that $\tau(X)=0$, since it can be rewritten as
$$-[X,[Z,-]_{\mathfrak{m}}]_{\mathfrak{m}}$$

By reductivity again, $\mathfrak{m}_0$ has an $\operatorname{Ad}(H)$-module complement $\mathfrak{m}_1$ in $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: I think this answers my question, Jose. Thanks. However, I was wondering whether there were any results of this nature in the literature. The Lie group result is well-known and I would have thought that it was generalized to reductive spaces.

Comment: Let me be a little more specific. Is it possible to view $\frak{m}$$_1$ as the Lie algebra of some subgroup of $G$?

Comment: I don't think that's true in general.  For example, for symmetric spaces $[\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m}]\subset \mathfrak{h}$.

Comment: For a symmetric space, the canonical connection has zero torsion and so $\frak{m}$$_1=0$. So the result is trivially true, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, indeed.  My mistake!  I'll have to think some more.  I don't see why it should be the case that $\mathfrak{m}_1$ is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$, but my alleged counterexample was too hasty.

Comment: I can check my claim with $S^7=Spin(7)/G_2$.